# Convert List<Pair<K, Collection<V>>> to Map<K,Collection<V>> in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, key-value, collectors

> Does anyone know how to convert a List<Pair<K, Collection< V >>> to
> Map<K,Collection< V >> in Kotlin, merging the collections associated with the same key?

In Java I would use something like:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (c1, c2) -> {
      List result = new ArrayList<>();
      result.addAll(c1);
      result.addAll(c2);
      return result;
})
```

Does Kotlin have a similar device, or a better one? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `Map<K,Collection<V>>` instead of `Map<K,V>`?

Comment: @Alex.T apologies, thank you, edited.

Comment: You mean you want to merge the lists corresponding to the same key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI, Kotlin has a [toMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-map.html) function exactly for that in cases where you don't need to merge the values of duplicate keys.

However, if you want to merge, you'll have to go with slightly more complicated. Assuming you have a list of pairs like this:

```kotlin
val pairs = listOf(
    1 to listOf("1", "2", "3"),
    1 to listOf("4"),
    2 to listOf("1", "2", "3"),
    3 to listOf("1", "2", "3"),
    3 to listOf("4", "5", "6"),
)
```

You can use [groupBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) and [mapValues](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html) like this:

```kotlin
val map = pairs.groupBy({ it.first }, { it.second })
               .mapValues { (k, v) -> v.flatten() }
```

The `groupBy` will create a `Map<Int, List<List<String>>>`, so each key will be mapped to the list of all the values corresponding to it. Then the `mapValues` flattens each list of lists so it becomes a single list.

Note that this create an intermediate map and may not be very efficient in performance-sensitive code compared to the provided Java. If you need efficiency, you can use [groupingBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html) instead to get a more lazy grouping and aggregate it as you please. For instance:

```kotlin
val map = pairs.groupingBy { it.first }
               .fold(emptyList<String>()) { acc, v -> acc + v.second }
```

which is nice but creates intermediate lists when merging. Or:

```kotlin
val map = pairs.groupingBy { it.first }.fold(
    initialValueSelector = { _, _ -> mutableListOf<String>() },
    operation = { _, acc, v -> acc.addAll(v.second); acc }
)
```

which creates a single list per key, but is a bit more complicated. Or another variant if you want to get crazier:

```kotlin
val map = pairs.groupingBy { it.first }.aggregate { k, acc: List<String>?, v, _ ->
    if (acc == null) v.second else acc + v.second
}
```

(which admittedly is a bit of a mouthful, and still creates intermediate lists)

Comment: Thank you Joffrey! Your first answer seems ideal in its simplicity :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `associate` to covert it. For exampe:

```kotlin
listOf(
    Pair(1, listOf("1", "2", "3")),
    Pair(2, listOf("1", "2", "3")),
    Pair(3, listOf("1", "2", "3"))
).associate { it.first to it.second }
```

The result is map:

```
{1=[1, 2, 3], 2=[1, 2, 3], 3=[1, 2, 3]}
```

If you need only first element as a value, you need to modify only value mapping to `it.second.first()`.

Comment: Apologies, question was wrong. Edited.